# How to download images from response of Readability Parser API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, readability, kindle

I'm using Readability Parser API to get content of the page.
After result received content goes to **kidlegen.exe**(to generate .mobi) and then to my kindle via email. The problem is content i get from Readability Parser API contains `<img>` to remote images, so i need to download them firts and only then launch **kindlegen.exe**.
The question is how to download remote images from article to my disk in efficient way? I can see only one solution - use regexp to parse response to extract `<img>`, then extract `scr` attribute and finally download images, but that's definitely worst way.
I'm using `ASP.NET MVC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i need `HtmlAgilityPack`. I'll detach this task from web application to console.